# What do I need to unit-test for this line of code using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, automapper

I've never used AutoMapper before, so I'm wondering what unit-tests I need to write for this specific line of code:

```
IEnumerable<UserDetail> userDetails = 
    this.mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.User>, IEnumerable<UserDetail>>(users);
```

the line in question is in this method:

```
public IEnumerable<UserDetail> GetUserDetails()
{
    var users = this.userData.GetUsers();

    //question is about testing this line
    IEnumerable<UserDetail> userDetails = 
        this.mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Entities.User>, IEnumerable<UserDetail>>(users);

    return userDetails;
}
```

Currently the unit-test provides a mock list of Users to return from `this.userData.GetUsers()` and then verifies the output `userDetails` contains the same data in `this.userData.GetUsers()`

This first unit-tests looks like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task VerifyAutoMapperProfile()
{
    //Assert
    this.MapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}

[Test]
public async Task UserService_GetUsers_Returns_IEnumerableUserDetails()
{
    //Arrange
    IList<Entities.User> usersFromData = this.GetMockUsers();

    Mock<IUserDataAccess> mockUserData = new Mock<IUserDataAccess>();

    mockUserData
        .Setup(d => d.GetUsers())
        .Returns(usersFromData);

    //this loads the same AutoMapper.Profile that the application uses
    IMapper mapper = this.MapperConfig.CreateMapper();

    var userService = new UserService(mockUserData.Object, mapper);

    //Act
    var userDetails = userService.GetUserDetails();

    //Assert
    userDetails.Should().BeAssignableTo<IEnumerable<UserDetail>>();
    userDetails.Should().HaveCount(usersFromData.Count);
    userDetails.Should().NotContainNulls();
    userDetails.Should().OnlyHaveUniqueItems();
    userDetails.Should().AllBeOfType<UserDetail>();

    foreach (Entities.User user in usersFromData)
    {
        var userDetail = new UserDetail {FullName = user.FullName, Guid = user.Guid};
        userDetails.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(userDetail);
    }
}
```

So question is, should I add any coverage in this test for the line I've indicated, or should I be creating separate tests for that line?  (I will be creating more unit-tests in general for this method - but my question is specifically asking about the `IMapper.Map` method.  Do I need to cover failures/exceptions thrown by that method? Is it enough just to have `this.MapperConfig.AssertConfigurationIsValid()`?

Answer (score 0):

In your **GetUserDetails()** method, you do 2 things. First is loading users, second is converting. So basically, your unit test just need to verify those 2 things. First is GetUsers() invoked or not? Second is Map() invoked or not? And 1 extra thing, if you load 10 users, you expect to get back 10 users (do NOT check the user properties).

WHY you don't need to check user properties? Because the mapping logic is not in your method, so you don't need to unit-test that.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  As I'm using a concrete implementation of `IMapper`, I'm not sure I can verify the `.Map` method was called without wrapping it in a Mock.  Is there a way to do that without putting it in a Mock?